# Cannot update my ADT plugin to v23.0.3

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to update ADT Plugin from version 22.3.0 to 23.0.3. But I'm getting this message everytime I try to update from within eclipse (from "Help->Install new software"). I even tried "Help->Check for updates" but it keeps on displaying "no updates found".

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>     Software being installed: Android Traceview 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)
>     Software currently installed: Android Developer Tools 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
>     Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>       Traceview 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview 23.0.3.1327240)
>       Traceview 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: ADT Package 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
>       To: com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 22.2.0
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Android Developer Tools 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
>       To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group [22.3.0.v201310242005-887826]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Android Traceview 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)
>       To: com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview [23.0.3.1327240]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Android Traceview 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
>       To: com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview [22.3.0.v201310242005-887826]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, and after messing with various solutions posted on SO, I just wiped my existing installation (hint: save the SDK folder is a seperate location, and then copy it back to you install so you don't have to download every SDK again).

Seems like this is the quickest way to recover from upgrade issues (at least for me) - to just install a new instance from scratch using the download bundle.