# Android SDK Download not working

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to download the Android SDK from the official page, but after accepting the Terms and Conditions the download does not begin. I am instead taken to the instructions page (on how to install the SDK).

I am trying to download from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. But after accepting the terms I am taken to http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=adt.

EDIT: I was successful with a different browser (please, see my answer below). I am reinstalling Eclipse ADT to solve [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269042/cannot-update-my-adt-plugin-to-v23-0-3) (updating ADT plugin to v23.0.3).

Comment: ur internet is too slow

Comment: If you have IDE with Android support (Android Studio or Eclipse ADT), you can use SDK Manager to download SDK: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html

Comment: I am reinstalling ADT because of the issue with ADT plugin v23.0.3. But strangely, the download was not working with Chrome. I used a different browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with a different browser (Firefox) and it is working. 
Strangely with Chrome (v36.0.1985.125) on OS X it was not working.